# robocopy based on earliest archived date?

Tags: file-io, backup, robocopy, batch-file

I want to then have "Data Files RC" in "C:\Laptop Backups" zipped with date on end of the file
so there will be:

```
C:\Laptop Backups\
    Data Files RC 9_22_2014.zip
    Data Files RC 9_23_2014.zip
    Data Files RC 9_24_2014.zip
    Data Files RC 9_25_2014.zip
```

Then I want to look at the earliest date in the "C:\Laptop Backups" directory based on the created date, 
not the date added to the file name, and delete any zipped files older than 14 days. So in the 
example above, I want to get the created date for "Data Files RC 9_25_2014.zip" then count back 14 days
and delete all zipped files older than 14 days.

I want to use the earliest file date, because if I am on vacation or just not paying attention
and the system fails, then the delete will not continue deleting files based on todays date.
If I do not catch this then it would eventually delete all backups.

So if something fails but the delete is still working it would only delete from 14 days back from
the point of failure, i.e. so say after 9-26-2014 the copy option is not working, but the 
delete is kicking in, then only 14 days back from 9-25-2014 would be deleted, then also on 9-27-2014 it would 
still only delete from 9-25-2014 14 days back, instead of using 9-27-2014.  This then would always have 14 days worth 
of backups from 9-25-2014 back.

Maybe this is not an issue, but I do have a routine that deletes based on todays date, then I have a separate 
backup software, which I just found was failing, so it occured to me that the delete batch routine that I put in Windows 
scheduler would have eventually deleted all my backups.

So what is the best way to avoid this, can robocopy be set to look at the earliest file date, then delete older files 
based on that or is there a some other script or combination thereof?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the latest 14 .zip files in a folder you can use this:  remove the `echo` to activate the delete command.
It sorts the ZIP files by date, always skips the 14 most recent files, and deletes the rest.

Ensure that the folder shown already exists.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Laptop Backups"
for /f "skip=14 delims=" %%a in ('dir *.zip /b /o-d /a-d') do echo del "%%a"
pause
```